# Creating a if statement dependent on a integer

Tags: ios, if-statement, count

Hi guys I'm trying to add a if statement into my code so that when the user clicks on the undo button they can undo it but only if the number if positive so if the number was zero then a message would pop up on there screen saying unable to undo count. A bit like a toast in android but whatever it is on ios

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  counter
//
//  Created by Charlotte on 23/06/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Charlotte. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)Up:(id)sender{

    Number=Number+1;
    Count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Number];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:Number forKey:@"savenumber"];
}

-(IBAction)Down:(id)sender{

    Number=Number-1;
    Count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Number];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:Number forKey:@"savenumber"];
}

-(IBAction)Restart:(id)sender{

    Number=0;
    Count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Number];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:Number forKey:@"savenumber"];
}






- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    Number = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"savenumber"];
    Count.Text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",Number];



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: where is if statement in this?

Comment: im yet to make it yet, i know how to do it for android but havent got a clue how to do it for apple

Comment: write if(Number == 0) { }

Comment: is that all I need to write?

Comment: yes. That is how we write if statement. Are you asking about if statement or toast? your question title tells about if inside you wrote something about toast. Exactly what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put Toast as in android go to https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/itoast and download library.
this will be the code to show toast. Drag iToast.h and .m file in your bundle.

In `viewController.m`

```
#import "iToast.h"
```

In method do this

```
   if(/*your condition here*/)
    {
        iToast * toast = [iToast makeText:@"Toast"];
        [toast setDuration:iToastDurationNormal];
        [toast show:iToastTypeInfo];
```

}

Comment: Is it this what you wanted?